# Value from Object using node

Tags: arrays, json, node.js

The below is my data, its type is object, I am not able to get my data after stringifying and parsing too...how can I get message alone using nodejs.

```
         [ { ID: '361',Message: 'customg' } ]
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question in a readable way and add more code to show us what you tried? It's just impossible to understand what you try to achieve.

Comment: You already have your data. It's sitting right there. What do you mean by "get my data"? Do you mean access elements in the array, or properties within the objects within the array? Why would you stringify and then parse, which would just give you what you started with?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to say is this. You got an array of object(s) like this:

```
var myarray =[ { ID: '361',Message: 'customg' } ] ;
```

stringifying the json object using JSON.stringify(myarray), gives :

```
"[{\"ID\":\"361\",\"Message\":\"customg\"}]"
```

parsing back using JSON.parse ("[{\"ID\":\"361\",\"Message\":\"customg\"}]"), returns your original object.

Now to access the 'Message' member, you need to access the first item in the array, then the Message property of the object, like this:

```
var msg =myarray [0].Message ;
```

This code assumes, you got an object with a property Message as the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is,

```
data = [ { ID: '361',Message: 'customg' } ]
```

data variable contains list of Objects(Here there is only one object in list).

```
var msg = data[0].Message // You will get message property
```

In your case you already have list of objects, so no need to stringify/parse the list.

```
JSON.stringify() : used when you want to convert your JSON object to string.

JSON.parse()     : used when you want JSON object from string.(given that string contains proper JSON object)
```